# Which item no is this minifigure head - prominent eyebrows raised in the middle, lots of teeth

Tags: part-identification, minifigure-identification

I'm searching for the item number of this minifigure head:

[image: minifig head]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: It's very close to 3626cpb2024 - but this shows more gap between the teeth.

Comment: Howdy Mister Dan, welcome to Bricks.SE.  Is your picture from a real-life model or was it 3d-rendered?  There are lots of amazing 3d-rendered LEGO pictures out there with parts that don't exist in those colors or with stuff printed on bricks that LEGO hasn't done yet.

Comment: The picture is from a Lego Stop Motion Film. Could be that the animator has digitally altered the face.

Answer (score 6):

I could only find minifigure head with same face expression but with freckles:

[Minifigure, Head Dark Brown Eyebrows, Dark Orange Freckles, Open Mouth Crooked Smile Pattern (Jay) - Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cpb1872&idColor=3#T=C&C=3) (3626cpb1872)

[image]

While I cannot yet confirm if this is the only piece with such face expression, it is not unheard of such modification (within LEGO community), where unwanted printing is removed.

Comment: I was just about to make this same suggestion!

Comment: It's very similar to that and another couple we have at home (same mouth, different eyebrows), to the extent I thought we had the right one